# Using use_spheroid=false in ST_DWithin of PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type, st-dwithin

I have created 2 geography columns and indexed them using `GIST`. I am looking to use `ST_DWithin` for a larger dataset and to make it faster trying to use the `use_spheroid=false`.

```
SELECT pois.objectid, ST_Multi(ST_Union(polygon.coordinates)) as coords   
              into table3
              FROM table1 as polygon 
              INNER JOIN table12 as pois 
              ON ST_DWithin(polygon.geog,pois.geog, 10* 1609.34, use_spheroid=false)
              group by pois.objectid
            limit 1;
```

but I get the following error,

```
ERROR:  column "use_spheroid" does not exist
```

Am I using the `use_spheroid=false` argument correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set it to false without naming it.

```
ST_DWithin(polygon.geog,pois.geog, 10* 1609.34, false)
```